# Exception: "Access to the path ... is denied"

Tags: c#, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm working on a program in C#, a part of which is to create a directory in the `Application.StartupPath` folder and then write a text file inside it using `System.IO.File.WriteAllText()`. My issue is that my program crashes, throwing an `UnauthorizedAccessException` and telling me that "Access to the path is denied", which is, well, odd, considering that it crashes regardless of the directory from which I am running the program, whether it be running from my cloud folders, Desktop, My Documents, etc, and even despite running it as Administrator in any of those directories.

The path from which I'm debugging it is `C:\Users\Jeff\Google Drive\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Palobo\Palobo\bin\Debug`. It is `using System.IO;`, and the code I'm using includes:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath);
File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath, "Password=" + x);
```

where `x` is some String data entered by the user.

The error I get is:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\Jeff\Google Drive\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Palobo\mzdon29 is denied.

(mzdon29 being an encrypted result of jwalk96).

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I'm encountering this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the exe externally or are you attemping to run this through the debugger in your IDE?

Comment: Both, and either way I get the same result.

Comment: Can you show us the code around the line where the error is occuring?

Comment: I think your account does not have write access to that location. That is the reason why its failing.

Comment: Could you please debug and tell us the actual value you are returning from Application.StartupPath

Comment: @Jeff Can you please add the code to your question? Thanks.

Comment: @jsve and @Jesse Carter: The path from which I'm debugging it is C:\Users\Jeff\Google Drive\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Palobo\Palobo\bin\Debug. It is `using System.IO;`, and the code I'm using includes:

`Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath);
File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath, "Password=" + x);`, where x is some String data entered by the user.

What I get in return is: **Access to the path 'C:\Users\Jeff\Google Drive\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Palobo\Palobo\mzdon29' is denied.** (mzdon29 being an encrypted result of jwalk96).

Answer (score 8):

`Application.StartupPath` is a folder (where your application is started from). Try to specify an exact filename inside that folder:

```
File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\MyFile.txt", "Password=" + x);
```

Comment: Ah, I see what I did. Thank you @Joel Coehoorn and @nXu!

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at this code:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath);
File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath, "Password=" + x);
```

You're trying to create a directory that already exists, and then you're trying use the directory as a file name! You need to add something to end of the path, so that you're working with a new folder and file.

Also, using the StartupPath for this is poor practice in the first place. You can create a shortcut that sets the startup path to *anywhere*. But specifically, it's common for the default StartupPath to be somewhere under the Program Files folder. Items under this folder are *read only* to standard users by default. Instead, you should look at using the Application Data folder, like so:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Finally, this sure looks like it's saving a password in plain-text. Do I really need to go over how bad that is? **You shouldn't even save passwords *encrypted*** (hashing is different than encryption), and this is one of those things that's so important you shouldn't even do it for testing/learning/proof of concept code.